# Realtime db Security Rules: validate each item in an array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In the Realtime Database Security Rules you can validate whether a string matches a regex code:

```
".validate": "newData.val().matches(/#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}\b/)"
```

But now let's suppose `newData` is an **Array** of strings (`String[]`), and each item in the string needs to match that same regex code. Can that be achieved?

I have already started to use the Firebase Bolt compiler, where I have:

```
validate() {
  this.background_colors.test(/#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}\b/)
}
```

But I just don't know how to do the same if it's an array and this needs to be validated for each item in that array, instead of a single string. I tried the code block below, but that doesn't fly with the compiler.

```
this.background_colors.each((color) => {
  color.test(/#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}\b/);
});
```

Comment: As per [Bolt's development status](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt#status), this is no longer in active development.